# Connect to FTP server via Unix terminal (explicit over TLS/SSL)

Tags: linux

I have a requirement to connect to a remote ftp server via unix terminal. I don't have gui access. The server runs ftp explicit over tls/ssl.

Could someone please help me with this?

I saw a post regarding the same using Ruby, but I need to do this without using any scripting languages. I can use only linux shell scripts and download commands if available.

Comment: what have you tried so far? also -link the ruby script so we can better understand exactly what you want done.

Comment: It is always better to add the references which you have come across with the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for a suitable ftp client try [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/). It is available in most linux distribution repositories. E.g. on debian, you can install it with

```
apt-get install lftp
```

You may get a certificate verification error when connecting to an ftp server which provides a self-signed certificate. In such a case you can disable certificate verification with this lftp command:

```
set ssl:verify-certificate no
```

However, be certain that you know what you are doing. Only disable certificate verification for own/trusted servers!